# Call the method of an element selected with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, methods

I have an element which has a user-defined method. The element is created as part of a larger object and inserted on the loading of the document. I can call that method at any point if I do so by addressing the element from the object directly.

The element is `tabs[0].bubbles[0].element` and the method is `.expand()`

(there are multiple elements within this object, each with their own .expand() method)

So, the line

```
tabs[0].bubbles[0].element.expand();
```

calls the method for that element. However, when an specific event occurs, a function is called from which I can select the element like so:

```
bubble = $(this).parent(); // the bubble element is the event handlers parent
```

However, the lines

```
bubble.expand();
// or 
$(bubble).expand();
// or
$(bubble)[0].expand();
```

do not call the method.

The line

```
tabs[0].bubbles[0].element.expand();
```

does call the method. However, I cannot use this line to call the method because there are a number of different elements and I cannot find the index number of the array's elements from within the function.

I thought that I may not be selecting the correct element but

```
($(bubble)[0] === $(tabs[0].bubbles[0].element)[0])
```

returns true (obviously this only occurs whenever `bubble` is the element that should correspond to `tabs[0].bubbles[0].element`).

`tabs[0].bubbles[0].element` is not the same as `$(bubble)[0]` or `$(bubble)[0]`.

How can I call the method from within the function where it was selected using JQuery?

***EDIT***

I think the issue is in how I create the object. The element field of the object is created in a constructor method like this.

```
this.element = $('<div class="bubble ' + this.type + '">\
    <div class="bubbleCentre ' + this.state + ' "> \
        <img class="bubbleIcon" src="img/dash/' + this.icon + '"> \
        <span class="status">' + text + '</span> \
    </div> \
</div>');
```

the `.expand()` function is created like this.

```
this.element.expand = function ()
{
    // method
    alert('method executing');
}
```

I can call the method like this

```
tabs[0].bubbles[0].element.expand();
```

but `bubble.get(0).expand();` or `bubble.expand();` do nothing.

However, if I define the method like this:

```
this.element.get(0).expand = function ()
{
    // method
    alert('method executing');
}
```

I can now call the method as you would expect

```
bubble.get(0).expand(); // expands bubble as you would expect
```

This is sufficient as the method is called. It does seem like there should be a more straightforward way to do so. I don't see why jQuery needs to be involved except in selecting the bubble in the event callback function. Any thoughts?

I tried removing the $() from around the string when `.element` is being defined (and also taking out `.get(0)` when the `.expand()` method is defined) but then I could not call the method at all by no matter what way I tried.

Comment: Whilst 
`tabs[0].bubbles[0].element.expand();` calls the method as you would expect, `$(tabs[0].bubbles[0].element)[0].expand();` and  `$(tabs[0].bubbles[0].element).expand();` do nothing. This suggests to me that the issue lies in selecting the element with JQuery

Comment: use a console to log the elements and see what they are

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: console.log( item ) ...then look in console

Comment: In the console, `bubble` and `tabs[0].bubbles[0].element` both appear to log the same thing. That frustrates me since (bubble === tabs[0].bubbles[0].element) returns false and `bubble.expand();` does nothing.

Comment: your code is not easy to troubleshoot without seeing it in the DOM and being able to set break points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in how the element was created.

I now create the element like this:

```
this.element = document.createElement('div');                                                               // first create DOM element

// append child elements
$(this.element).addClass('bubble ' + this.type);
$('<div class="bubbleCentre ' + this.state + ' "></div>').appendTo(this.element)                            // append centre
.append('<img class="bubbleIcon" src="img/dash/' + this.icon + '" title="' + type.capitalize()  + '">')     // append icon to centre
.append('<span class="status">' + text + '</span>')                                                         // append status to centre
.parent().append('<div class="subbubbles"><div style="position: relative;"></div></div>');                  // append subbubbles box
```

I define the method like this:

```
this.element.expand = function ()
{
    // method running
    alert('method running');
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
bubble.get(0).expand();
```

That all seems to work. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method for each element of a matched set and/or get de value of the last match, you can create a new jquery function.

```
$.fn.invoke = function(name) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    var ret;

    this.each(function() {
        ret = this[name].apply(this, args);
    });

    return typeof ret !== 'undefined' ? ret : this;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eQLHT/